# Jenkins File Reference in Java

Tags: java, file, jenkins, io

I want to test my implemented CSV Parser.

Therefore i need to load a CSV test file, which ist stored in path

> project/src/test/resources/dataset/someFile.csv

I have tried three different ways to load that file into my test class.
**All of them work on my localhost environment.**

Attempt #1:

```
File file = new File("src/test/resources/dataset/someFile.csv");
```

Attempt #2:

```
String url = Resources.getResource("/dataset/someFile.csv").getFile();

File file = new File(url);
```

Attempt #3:

```
String url = getClass().getResource("/dataset/someFile.csv").getFile();

File file = new File(url);
```

As soon as I deploy it into the Jenkins Build Pipeline, several exceptions (Nullpointer and IllegalArgument caused by Nullpointer) appear.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource dataset/someFile.csv not found.
```

Any ideas why Jenkins isn't able to reference that file correctly?

Comment: Is `test` folder included in classpath?

Comment: I guess it is, in another class I use the annotation     @InsertData({"/dataset/someFile.xml"}) which works completely fine.